# php website : measure time between user click and displayed response

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I'm trying to see if there is such a tool for my problem.

I have a php website and every time I click on a link the response time is very long.
I'm watching the mysql queries and there is no slow query.
So, I'm wondering if there is any tool to be able to see which part is slow when a page is displayed ?
Is the database ? Is the host server ? Is something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) which measures time spent in the browser. Frontend load times are often forgotten when trying to optimize web pages.

Answer (score 1):

your browser could be of a great help here, to begin with.

Chrome (control maj J) provides useful tools for that.

For the rest, I guess you need some custom profiling of your php sql calls...

Answer (score 1):

There are also websites measuring it. One example http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/